# How can I map components of Azure Data Factory with informatica power center?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory, informatica-powercenter

I have started learning Azure Data Factory recently, I have used Informatica Powercenter for ETL. As I am going through the tutorial, I have come across ADF components like Pipeline, Dataset, Dataflow, Trigger, Integration runtime, etc. how can I map each of these components with Powercenter components. For E.g. Dataflow in ADF is like Mapping in Powercenter. Can someone who has worked on both these tools help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory is a fully managed, serverless data integration and data transformation (ETL/ELT) service in Azure.

Azure Data Factory is composed of below key components:

**1. Linked Service:** Linked services are much like connection strings, which define the connection information that's needed for Data Factory to connect to data sources like Azure SQL database, Blob Storage, Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, etc. For supported data stores, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores.

Sharing an example of linked service to connect with Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

**2. Dataset:** Datasets represent data structures within the data stores, which simply point to or reference the data you want to use in your activities as inputs or outputs. For example, if you want to transform the CSV data which is stored in Azure Blob storage and then store it in Azure SQL database, then your input dataset will be **DelimitedText** and output dataset will be **Table Name** in SQL database where your data will be stored after transformation. Azure Data Factory supports follwing file formats in Datasets:

- Avro format
- Binary format
- Delimited text format
- Excel format
- JSON format
- ORC format
- Parquet format
- XML format

**Note:** Linked Service is used when creating dataset.

**3. Mapping data flow:** Mapping data flows are visually designed data transformations in Azure Data Factory. Data flows allows to develop data transformation logic without writing code. Mapping data flows are authored using a design surface know as the data flow graph. In the graph, transformation logic is built left-to-right and additional data streams are added top-down. To know more, plz check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview

**4. Integration Runtime (IR)**: It is the compute infrastructure used by Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse pipelines to provide the data integration capabilities across different network environments. By default, each ADF has an Azure IR which it is used for data flow and other tasks. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime

**5. Pipeline:** Whatever activity or data flow we create in data factory runs as pipeline.

**6. Triggers:** To schedule the pipeline trigger based on certain criteria. For more details visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

These are the basic components when we build data transformation.

I suggest you to go through this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow). This will definitely help you for better insight.

Comment: I was asking how we can map each of these components with Informatica Powercenter?

Comment: You can't map these components in Informatica Powercenter because Azure data factory is separate service. Either you use ADF or Informatica.